# Get AsyncTask class status android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using a async class to do a task,I need to get the status of the asynctask...

```
new Asyncimg().execute();
if(AsyncTask.Status==AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)
```

This shows an error.
How can i resolve this issue...

Comment: store the reference of asynctask object and use that object to see the status

Comment: what you want to do ?

Comment: What are the errors ??

Answer (score 2):

You can override onProgressUpdate() method and check its status.

Answer (score 1):

```
    First thing is declare your AsyncTask Class globe like 

    private AsyncTaskUserLike asyncTaskUserLike;

    then check the status of your asynctask 

    if (asyncTaskUserLike != null && asyncTaskUserLike.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.PENDING) {
                asyncTaskUserLike.execute();
            } else if (asyncTaskUserLike == null || asyncTaskUserLike.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
                asyncTaskUserLike = new AsyncTaskUserLike();
                asyncTaskUserLike.execute();
            }

Same as above you can check for running status like,

asyncTaskUserLike.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
task.execute();
while(task.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)) {

};
doWork();
```

[check this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.Status.html)